# First painful attempt to do a Spatial map

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I am struggling to get my first map to work. I have read every document I could find but I am not able to pull it all together to view my data on a map.

This is what I have done so far.
1. I created a very basic data table with 3 observations and 5 variables as a very simple starting point.

```
str(Datawithlatlongnotvector)

    'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ Client: Factor w/ 3 levels "Jan","Piet","Susan": 2 1 3
     $ Sales : int  100 1000 15000
     $ Lat   : num  26.2 33.9 23.9
     $ Lon   : num  28 18.4 29.4
     $ Area  : Factor w/ 3 levels "Gauteng","Limpopo",..: 1 3 2
```

(the Area is the provinces of South Africa and also is as per the SHP file that I downloaded, see below)

2. I downloaded a map of South Africa and placed all 3 files (.dbf, shp and shx) files in the same directory - previous error  but I found the answer from another user's question. http://www.mapmakerdata.co.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/library/stacks/Africa/South%20Africa/index.htm and selected Simple base map.
3. I created a map as follows :

   `SAMap <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "SOU-level_1")`

and I can plot the map of the country showing the provinces with plot(SAMap)

4. I can also plot the data

   `plot(datawithlatlong)`
5. I saw the instructions how to make a SpatialPointsData frame and I did that :

   `coordinates(Datawithlatlong) = ~Lat + Lon`
6. I do not know how to pull it all together and do the following :
   Show the data (100,1000 and 15000) on the map with different colours i.e. between 1 and 500 is one colour, between 501 and 10 000 is one colour and above 10 000 is one colour.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose that shapefile? `bbox(SAMap)` has a latitude range of `16.45545, 38.00047` and a longitude range of `-46.97893, -22.12607` which clearly do not fit your data. Also, are you trying to make a choropleth? Draw single dots? Draw scaled circles? And, finally, output of `dput(Datawithlatlongnotvector)` would be more helpful than `str()`

Comment: Which shapefile did you download? The simple base map as mentioned in the question is an image and no shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying `ggplot2` with some function like:

```
   map = ggplot(df, aes(long, lat, fill = Sales_cat)) +  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Oranges", name = "Sales") + geom_polygon()
```

With [`scale_fill_brewer`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggplot2/docs/scale_brewer) you can represent scales in terms of colours on the map. You should create a `factor` variable that represents categories according to the range of sales ("`Sales_cat`"). In any case, the shape file must be transformed into a `data.frame`.

Comment: Why would you assume the OP "has done so" when they are self-admitting they are struggling and have only provided a base plot example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 'SAMap' as the country shapefile and 'datawithlatlong' as your data convereted to SpatialPointDataFrame:

```
library(maptools)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Prepare colour pallete  
plotclr <- brewer.pal(3,"PuRd")
class<-classIntervals(datawithlatlong@data$sales, n=3, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=c(0, 500,1000,10000)) # you can adjust the intervals here 
colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)

# Plot country map
plot(SAMap,xlim=c(16, 38.0), ylim=c(-46,-23))# plot your polygon shapefile with appropriate xlim and ylim (extent)

# Plot dataframe convereted to SPDF (in your step 5)
plot(datawithlatlong, col=colcode, add=T,pch=19)

# Creating the legend
legend(16.2, -42, legend=names(attr(colcode, "table")), fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6, bty="n") # adjust the x and y for fixing appropriate location for the legend
```

Comment: Hi there   How do I map the data into the country map ?

Comment: Is your data in SpatialPointsDataFrame after step 5 (now called datawithlatlong)? And your country map is shapefile SMAP?

Answer (score 0):

I generated a bigger dataset because I think with only 3 points it hard to see how things are working.

```
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
library(ggmap)
library(randomNames)

#I downloaded the shapefile with the administrative area polygons
map <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "SOU")

#the coordinate system is not part of the loaded object hence I added this information
proj4string(map) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# Some sample data with random client names and random region 
ADM2   <- sample(map@data$ADM2, replace = TRUE, 50)
name   <- randomNames(50)
sales  <- sample(0:5000, 50)

clientData <- data.frame(id = 1:50, name, region = as.character(ADM2), sales,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#In order to add the geoinformation for each client I used the awesome 
#function `ggmap::geocode` which takes a character string as input an 
#provides the lon and lat for the region, city ...

geoinfo <- geocode(clientData$region, messaging = FALSE)

# Use this information to build a Point layer
clientData_point <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(geoinfo, data = clientData)
proj4string(clientData_point) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

Now the part I hope that answers the question:

```
# Adding all sales which occured in one region
# If there are 3 clients in one region, the sales of the three are 
# summed up and returned in a new layer
sales_map <- aggregate(x = clientData_point[ ,4], by = map, FUN = sum)

# Building a map using the `tmap` package`
tm_shape(sales_map) + tm_polygons(col = "sales")
```

[image]

## Edit:

Here is a `ggplot2` solution because it seems you want to stick with it.

First, for ggplot you have to transform your `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` to an ordinary `data.frame`. Fortunately, `broom::tidy()` will do the job automatically.
Second, your `Lat` values are missing a `-`. I added it.
Third, I renamed your objects for less typing.

```
point_layer<- structure(list(Client = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L),
                            .Label = c("Jan", "Piet", "Susan"), 
                             class = "factor"), 
                             Sales = c(100, 1000, 15000 ), 
                             Lat = c(-26.2041, -33.9249, -23.8962), 
                             Lon = c(28.0473, 18.4241, 29.4486), 
                             Area = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), 
                            .Label = c("Gauteng", "Limpopo", "Western Cape"), 
                             class = "factor"), 
                             Sale_range = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L), 
                            .Label = c("(1,500]", "(500,2e+03]", "(2e+03,5e+03]", "(5e+03,5e+04]"), 
                            class = "factor")), 
                            .Names = c("Client", "Sales", "Lat", "Lon", "Area", "Sale_range"), 
                             row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame") 

point_layer$Sale_range <- cut(point_layer$Sales, c(1,500.0,2000.0,5000.0,50000.0 )) 

library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot_map <- tidy(map)

ggplot() + geom_polygon(ggplot_map, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                        fill = "grey65", color = "black") +
           geom_point(point_layer, mapping = aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, col = Sale_range)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Oranges", direction = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.  I think we are getting closer.  I created a Sales range with the following command: Datawithlatlongnotvector$Sale_range <- cut(Datawithlatlongnotvector$Sales, c(1,500.0,2000.0,5000.0,50000.0 )) . The str looks as follows : str(Datawithlatlongnotvector)
'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Client    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Jan","Piet","Susan": 2 1 3
 $ Sales     : num  100 1000 15000
 $ Lat       : num  26.2 33.9 23.9
 $ Lon       : num  28 18.4 29.4
 $ Area      : Factor w/ 3 levels "Gauteng","Limpopo",..: 1 3 2
 $ Sale_range: Factor w/ 4 levels "(1,500]","(500,2e+03]",..: 1 2 4

Comment: I then ran the command map = ggplot(Datawithlatlongnotvector, aes(Lon, Lat, fill = Sale_range)) +  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Oranges", name = "Sales") + geom_polygon()  . After that I ran print(map)  and the map was produced but it is empty.  My questions are : why is it empty and how do I overlap the country map ?

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(Datawithlatlongnotvector)`.

Comment: dput(Datawithlatlongnotvector)
structure(list(Client = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Piet", "Susan"), class = "factor"), Sales = c(100, 1000, 15000
), Lat = c(26.2041, 33.9249, 23.8962), Lon = c(28.0473, 18.4241, 
29.4486), Area = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Gauteng", 
"Limpopo", "Western Cape"), class = "factor"), Sale_range = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 4L), .Label = c("(1,500]", "(500,2e+03]", "(2e+03,5e+03]", 
"(5e+03,5e+04]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Client", "Sales", 
"Lat", "Lon", "Area", "Sale_range"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Is that more to your like?